# open corresponding div on click and close prevous div if opened

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have below html code now i want to show each block in on page load

```
<div class="view-grouping-header">
   <a href="/product/footbal">
        <img src="footbal.png.jpg">
     </a>
     <h1 class="product-header-title">football world cup</h1>
  </div>
```

and want to hide div start from below code on load in each block `<div class="view-grouping-content">`

now if I click on any on block title: `<h1>football world cup</h1>` then corresponding div starting `<div class="view-grouping-content">` should be open. Also if click on other block title previous open div should be closed

```js
jQuery(function($){
    $('.view-grouping-content').hide()
    $('.product-header-title').click(function(e){
       $('.view-grouping-content').show();  
    });
});
```

```css
.view-grouping-content{ display:none}
```

```html
<div class="view-content">
   <div class="view-grouping">
      <div class="view-grouping-header">
         <a href="/product/footbal">
            <img src="footbal.png.jpg">
         </a>
         <h1 class="product-header-title">football world cup</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="view-grouping-content">
         <h3>Football is a family of team sports that involve, to varying degrees, kicking a ball to score a goal. Unqualified, the word football normally means the form of football that is the most popular where the word is used. <div class="product-page-link">
               <a href="/product/footbal">Learn More</a>
            </div>
         </h3> football world leaguge <p>There are conflicting explanations of the origin of the word "football". It is widely assumed that the word "football" (or the phrase "foot ball") refers to the action of the foot kicking a ball.[12] There is an alternative explanation, which is that football originally referred to a variety of games in medieval Europe that were played on foot.[13] There is no conclusive evidence for either explanation. </p> football world cup <p>There are conflicting explanations of the origin of the word "football". It is widely assumed that the word "football" (or the phrase "foot ball") refers to the action of the foot kicking a ball.[12] There is an alternative explanation, which is that football originally referred to a variety of games in medieval Europe that were played on foot.[13] There is no conclusive evidence for either explanation.</p>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="view-grouping">
      <div class="view-grouping-header">
         <a href="/product/footbal">
            <img src="footbal.png.jpg">
         </a>
         <h1 class="product-header-title">football world cup</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="view-grouping-content">
         <h3>Football is a family of team sports that involve, to varying degrees, kicking a ball to score a goal. Unqualified, the word football normally means the form of football that is the most popular where the word is used. <div class="product-page-link">
               <a href="/product/footbal">Learn More</a>
            </div>
         </h3> football world leaguge <p>There are conflicting explanations of the origin of the word "football". It is widely assumed that the word "football" (or the phrase "foot ball") refers to the action of the foot kicking a ball.[12] There is an alternative explanation, which is that football originally referred to a variety of games in medieval Europe that were played on foot.[13] There is no conclusive evidence for either explanation. </p> football world cup <p>There are conflicting explanations of the origin of the word "football". It is widely assumed that the word "football" (or the phrase "foot ball") refers to the action of the foot kicking a ball.[12] There is an alternative explanation, which is that football originally referred to a variety of games in medieval Europe that were played on foot.[13] There is no conclusive evidence for either explanation.</p>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="view-grouping">
      <div class="view-grouping-header">
         <a href="/product/footbal">
            <img src="footbal.png.jpg">
         </a>
         <h1 class="product-header-title">football world cup</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="view-grouping-content">
         <h3>Football is a family of team sports that involve, to varying degrees, kicking a ball to score a goal. Unqualified, the word football normally means the form of football that is the most popular where the word is used. <div class="product-page-link">
               <a href="/product/footbal">Learn More</a>
            </div>
         </h3> football world leaguge <p>There are conflicting explanations of the origin of the word "football". It is widely assumed that the word "football" (or the phrase "foot ball") refers to the action of the foot kicking a ball.[12] There is an alternative explanation, which is that football originally referred to a variety of games in medieval Europe that were played on foot.[13] There is no conclusive evidence for either explanation. </p> football world cup <p>There are conflicting explanations of the origin of the word "football". It is widely assumed that the word "football" (or the phrase "foot ball") refers to the action of the foot kicking a ball.[12] There is an alternative explanation, which is that football originally referred to a variety of games in medieval Europe that were played on foot.[13] There is no conclusive evidence for either explanation.</p>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="view-grouping">
      <div class="view-grouping-header">
         <a href="/product/footbal">
            <img src="footbal.png.jpg">
         </a>
         <h1 class="product-header-title">football world cup</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="view-grouping-content">
         <h3>Football is a family of team sports that involve, to varying degrees, kicking a ball to score a goal. Unqualified, the word football normally means the form of football that is the most popular where the word is used. <div class="product-page-link">
               <a href="/product/footbal">Learn More</a>
            </div>
         </h3> football world leaguge <p>There are conflicting explanations of the origin of the word "football". It is widely assumed that the word "football" (or the phrase "foot ball") refers to the action of the foot kicking a ball.[12] There is an alternative explanation, which is that football originally referred to a variety of games in medieval Europe that were played on foot.[13] There is no conclusive evidence for either explanation. </p> football world cup <p>There are conflicting explanations of the origin of the word "football". It is widely assumed that the word "football" (or the phrase "foot ball") refers to the action of the foot kicking a ball.[12] There is an alternative explanation, which is that football originally referred to a variety of games in medieval Europe that were played on foot.[13] There is no conclusive evidence for either explanation.</p>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="view-grouping">
      <div class="view-grouping-header">
         <a href="/product/footbal">
            <img src="footbal.png.jpg">
         </a>
         <h1 class="product-header-title">football world cup</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="view-grouping-content">
         <h3>Football is a family of team sports that involve, to varying degrees, kicking a ball to score a goal. Unqualified, the word football normally means the form of football that is the most popular where the word is used. <div class="product-page-link">
               <a href="/product/footbal">Learn More</a>
            </div>
         </h3> football world leaguge <p>There are conflicting explanations of the origin of the word "football". It is widely assumed that the word "football" (or the phrase "foot ball") refers to the action of the foot kicking a ball.[12] There is an alternative explanation, which is that football originally referred to a variety of games in medieval Europe that were played on foot.[13] There is no conclusive evidence for either explanation. </p> football world cup <p>There are conflicting explanations of the origin of the word "football". It is widely assumed that the word "football" (or the phrase "foot ball") refers to the action of the foot kicking a ball.[12] There is an alternative explanation, which is that football originally referred to a variety of games in medieval Europe that were played on foot.[13] There is no conclusive evidence for either explanation.</p>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="view-grouping">
      <div class="view-grouping-header">
         <a href="/product/footbal">
            <img src="footbal.png.jpg">
         </a>
         <h1 class="product-header-title">football world cup</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="view-grouping-content">
         <h3>Football is a family of team sports that involve, to varying degrees, kicking a ball to score a goal. Unqualified, the word football normally means the form of football that is the most popular where the word is used. <div class="product-page-link">
               <a href="/product/footbal">Learn More</a>
            </div>
         </h3> football world leaguge <p>There are conflicting explanations of the origin of the word "football". It is widely assumed that the word "football" (or the phrase "foot ball") refers to the action of the foot kicking a ball.[12] There is an alternative explanation, which is that football originally referred to a variety of games in medieval Europe that were played on foot.[13] There is no conclusive evidence for either explanation. </p> football world cup <p>There are conflicting explanations of the origin of the word "football". It is widely assumed that the word "football" (or the phrase "foot ball") refers to the action of the foot kicking a ball.[12] There is an alternative explanation, which is that football originally referred to a variety of games in medieval Europe that were played on foot.[13] There is no conclusive evidence for either explanation.</p>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="view-grouping">
      <div class="view-grouping-header">
         <a href="/product/footbal">
            <img src="footbal.png.jpg">
         </a>
         <h1 class="product-header-title">football world cup</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="view-grouping-content">
         <h3>Football is a family of team sports that involve, to varying degrees, kicking a ball to score a goal. Unqualified, the word football normally means the form of football that is the most popular where the word is used. <div class="product-page-link">
               <a href="/product/footbal">Learn More</a>
            </div>
         </h3> football world leaguge <p>There are conflicting explanations of the origin of the word "football". It is widely assumed that the word "football" (or the phrase "foot ball") refers to the action of the foot kicking a ball.[12] There is an alternative explanation, which is that football originally referred to a variety of games in medieval Europe that were played on foot.[13] There is no conclusive evidence for either explanation. </p> football world cup <p>There are conflicting explanations of the origin of the word "football". It is widely assumed that the word "football" (or the phrase "foot ball") refers to the action of the foot kicking a ball.[12] There is an alternative explanation, which is that football originally referred to a variety of games in medieval Europe that were played on foot.[13] There is no conclusive evidence for either explanation.</p>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: From the [javascript tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/javascript/info): "*[JavaScript] is unrelated to the Java programming language and shares only superficial similarities. ...*"

Comment: so where is the code that is doing the showing and hiding?

Comment: What have you tried? We do expect that you'll make an attempt at a solution before posting here and then, when you do post, we expect that you'll post your attempt and describe what aspect of your attempt isn't working and/or what question you have about it.

Comment: Scott Marcus See the jQuery I have written

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to hide `div` inside `document.ready`  because CSS already hide that `div` using `display: none`.

On `product-header-title` click, first of all hide your all div which has class `view-grouping-content` and show desire `div` with the help of `parent()` and `next()`.

Example:

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  $('.product-header-title').click(function(e) {
    $('.view-grouping-content').hide();
    $(this).parent('div').next('.view-grouping-content').show();
  });
});
```

```css
.view-grouping-content {
  display: none
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="view-content">
  <div class="view-grouping">
    <div class="view-grouping-header">
      <a href="/product/footbal">
        <img src="footbal.png.jpg">
      </a>
      <h1 class="product-header-title">football world cup</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="view-grouping-content">
      <h3>Football is a family of team sports that involve, to varying degrees, kicking a ball to score a goal. Unqualified, the word football normally means the form of football that is the most popular where the word is used.
        <div class="product-page-link">
          <a href="/product/footbal">Learn More</a>
        </div>
      </h3> football world leaguge
      <p>There are conflicting explanations of the origin of the word "football". It is widely assumed that the word "football" (or the phrase "foot ball") refers to the action of the foot kicking a ball.[12] There is an alternative explanation, which is
        that football originally referred to a variety of games in medieval Europe that were played on foot.[13] There is no conclusive evidence for either explanation. </p> football world cup
      <p>There are conflicting explanations of the origin of the word "football". It is widely assumed that the word "football" (or the phrase "foot ball") refers to the action of the foot kicking a ball.[12] There is an alternative explanation, which is
        that football originally referred to a variety of games in medieval Europe that were played on foot.[13] There is no conclusive evidence for either explanation.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="view-grouping">
    <div class="view-grouping-header">
      <a href="/product/footbal">
        <img src="footbal.png.jpg">
      </a>
      <h1 class="product-header-title">football world cup</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="view-grouping-content">
      <h3>Football is a family of team sports that involve, to varying degrees, kicking a ball to score a goal. Unqualified, the word football normally means the form of football that is the most popular where the word is used.
        <div class="product-page-link">
          <a href="/product/footbal">Learn More</a>
        </div>
      </h3> football world leaguge
      <p>There are conflicting explanations of the origin of the word "football". It is widely assumed that the word "football" (or the phrase "foot ball") refers to the action of the foot kicking a ball.[12] There is an alternative explanation, which is
        that football originally referred to a variety of games in medieval Europe that were played on foot.[13] There is no conclusive evidence for either explanation. </p> football world cup
      <p>There are conflicting explanations of the origin of the word "football". It is widely assumed that the word "football" (or the phrase "foot ball") refers to the action of the foot kicking a ball.[12] There is an alternative explanation, which is
        that football originally referred to a variety of games in medieval Europe that were played on foot.[13] There is no conclusive evidence for either explanation.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="view-grouping">
    <div class="view-grouping-header">
      <a href="/product/footbal">
        <img src="footbal.png.jpg">
      </a>
      <h1 class="product-header-title">football world cup</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="view-grouping-content">
      <h3>Football is a family of team sports that involve, to varying degrees, kicking a ball to score a goal. Unqualified, the word football normally means the form of football that is the most popular where the word is used.
        <div class="product-page-link">
          <a href="/product/footbal">Learn More</a>
        </div>
      </h3> football world leaguge
      <p>There are conflicting explanations of the origin of the word "football". It is widely assumed that the word "football" (or the phrase "foot ball") refers to the action of the foot kicking a ball.[12] There is an alternative explanation, which is
        that football originally referred to a variety of games in medieval Europe that were played on foot.[13] There is no conclusive evidence for either explanation. </p> football world cup
      <p>There are conflicting explanations of the origin of the word "football". It is widely assumed that the word "football" (or the phrase "foot ball") refers to the action of the foot kicking a ball.[12] There is an alternative explanation, which is
        that football originally referred to a variety of games in medieval Europe that were played on foot.[13] There is no conclusive evidence for either explanation.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="view-grouping">
    <div class="view-grouping-header">
      <a href="/product/footbal">
        <img src="footbal.png.jpg">
      </a>
      <h1 class="product-header-title">football world cup</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="view-grouping-content">
      <h3>Football is a family of team sports that involve, to varying degrees, kicking a ball to score a goal. Unqualified, the word football normally means the form of football that is the most popular where the word is used.
        <div class="product-page-link">
          <a href="/product/footbal">Learn More</a>
        </div>
      </h3> football world leaguge
      <p>There are conflicting explanations of the origin of the word "football". It is widely assumed that the word "football" (or the phrase "foot ball") refers to the action of the foot kicking a ball.[12] There is an alternative explanation, which is
        that football originally referred to a variety of games in medieval Europe that were played on foot.[13] There is no conclusive evidence for either explanation. </p> football world cup
      <p>There are conflicting explanations of the origin of the word "football". It is widely assumed that the word "football" (or the phrase "foot ball") refers to the action of the foot kicking a ball.[12] There is an alternative explanation, which is
        that football originally referred to a variety of games in medieval Europe that were played on foot.[13] There is no conclusive evidence for either explanation.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="view-grouping">
    <div class="view-grouping-header">
      <a href="/product/footbal">
        <img src="footbal.png.jpg">
      </a>
      <h1 class="product-header-title">football world cup</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="view-grouping-content">
      <h3>Football is a family of team sports that involve, to varying degrees, kicking a ball to score a goal. Unqualified, the word football normally means the form of football that is the most popular where the word is used.
        <div class="product-page-link">
          <a href="/product/footbal">Learn More</a>
        </div>
      </h3> football world leaguge
      <p>There are conflicting explanations of the origin of the word "football". It is widely assumed that the word "football" (or the phrase "foot ball") refers to the action of the foot kicking a ball.[12] There is an alternative explanation, which is
        that football originally referred to a variety of games in medieval Europe that were played on foot.[13] There is no conclusive evidence for either explanation. </p> football world cup
      <p>There are conflicting explanations of the origin of the word "football". It is widely assumed that the word "football" (or the phrase "foot ball") refers to the action of the foot kicking a ball.[12] There is an alternative explanation, which is
        that football originally referred to a variety of games in medieval Europe that were played on foot.[13] There is no conclusive evidence for either explanation.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="view-grouping">
    <div class="view-grouping-header">
      <a href="/product/footbal">
        <img src="footbal.png.jpg">
      </a>
      <h1 class="product-header-title">football world cup</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="view-grouping-content">
      <h3>Football is a family of team sports that involve, to varying degrees, kicking a ball to score a goal. Unqualified, the word football normally means the form of football that is the most popular where the word is used.
        <div class="product-page-link">
          <a href="/product/footbal">Learn More</a>
        </div>
      </h3> football world leaguge
      <p>There are conflicting explanations of the origin of the word "football". It is widely assumed that the word "football" (or the phrase "foot ball") refers to the action of the foot kicking a ball.[12] There is an alternative explanation, which is
        that football originally referred to a variety of games in medieval Europe that were played on foot.[13] There is no conclusive evidence for either explanation. </p> football world cup
      <p>There are conflicting explanations of the origin of the word "football". It is widely assumed that the word "football" (or the phrase "foot ball") refers to the action of the foot kicking a ball.[12] There is an alternative explanation, which is
        that football originally referred to a variety of games in medieval Europe that were played on foot.[13] There is no conclusive evidence for either explanation.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="view-grouping">
    <div class="view-grouping-header">
      <a href="/product/footbal">
        <img src="footbal.png.jpg">
      </a>
      <h1 class="product-header-title">football world cup</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="view-grouping-content">
      <h3>Football is a family of team sports that involve, to varying degrees, kicking a ball to score a goal. Unqualified, the word football normally means the form of football that is the most popular where the word is used.
        <div class="product-page-link">
          <a href="/product/footbal">Learn More</a>
        </div>
      </h3> football world leaguge
      <p>There are conflicting explanations of the origin of the word "football". It is widely assumed that the word "football" (or the phrase "foot ball") refers to the action of the foot kicking a ball.[12] There is an alternative explanation, which is
        that football originally referred to a variety of games in medieval Europe that were played on foot.[13] There is no conclusive evidence for either explanation. </p> football world cup
      <p>There are conflicting explanations of the origin of the word "football". It is widely assumed that the word "football" (or the phrase "foot ball") refers to the action of the foot kicking a ball.[12] There is an alternative explanation, which is
        that football originally referred to a variety of games in medieval Europe that were played on foot.[13] There is no conclusive evidence for either explanation.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```